# Windows 8 - How to get nested folder properly?

Tags: c#, windows, asynchronous, windows-8, windows-runtime

I have a GridView that's bound to a collection of objects which load images from the disk.

The objects are put onto a stack when they become visible, and the images are loaded off the stack sequentially.

The problem is that GetFolderAsync() doesn't return until the ScrollViewer containing the objects has stopped scrolling.

The code is as below:

```
    public static async Task<StorageFolder> GetFileFolderAsync(String fileUrl)
    {
        try
        {
            string filePathRelative = DownloadedFilePaths.GetRelativeFilePathFromUrl(fileUrl);
            string[] words = filePathRelative.Split('\\');
            StorageFolder currentFolder = await DownloadedFilePaths.GetAppDownloadsFolder();
            for (int i = 0; (i < words.Length - 1); i++)
            {
                //this is where it "waits" for the scroll viewer to slow down/stop
                currentFolder = await currentFolder.GetFolderAsync(words[i]);
            }
            return currentFolder;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

I've pinpointed it down to that line where it gets the folder that contains the image. Is this even the proper way to get a nested folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the method I was using to determine the object's visibility was blocking the UI thread.

> I have a GridView that's bound to a collection of objects which load images from the disk.
>
> **The objects are put onto a stack when they become visible**, and the images are loaded off the stack sequentially.
>
> The problem is that GetFolderAsync() doesn't return until the ScrollViewer containing the objects has stopped scrolling.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use `ConfigureAwait(false)` to run the `for` loop on a thread pool thread:

```
public static async Task<StorageFolder> GetFileFolderAsync(String fileUrl)
{
    try
    {
        string filePathRelative = DownloadedFilePaths.GetRelativeFilePathFromUrl(fileUrl);
        string[] words = filePathRelative.Split('\\');
        // HERE added ConfigureAwait call
        StorageFolder currentFolder = await
            DownloadedFilePaths.GetAppDownloadsFolder().ConfigureAwait(false);
        // Code that follows ConfigureAwait(false) call will (usually) be 
        // scheduled on a background (non-UI) thread.
        for (int i = 0; (i < words.Length - 1); i++)
        {
            // should no longer be on the UI thread, 
            // so scrollviewer will no longer block
            currentFolder = await currentFolder.GetFolderAsync(words[i]);
        }
        return currentFolder;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Note that in the above case since there is no work that is done on the UI, you CAN use `ConfigureAwait(false)`. For example, the following would not work because there is a UI related call after the `ConfigureAwait`:

```
// HERE added ConfigureAwait call
StorageFolder currentFolder = await
    DownloadedFilePaths.GetAppDownloadsFolder().ConfigureAwait(false);
// Can fail because execution is possibly not on UI thread anymore:
myTextBox.Text = currentFolder.Path;
```